# Cloud function deployment is failing due to missing node modules mentioned in your package-lock.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My cloud function deployment failing repeatedly due to missing dependencies. Have tried removing node_modules & package-lock.json without success. Attempting to set a custom claim to create an admin user:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.assignAdminRole = functions
    .region("australia-southeast1")
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      // Note: Replace USER_ID with the actual user ID
      const userId = "Zjo31SJpuCRoGwPdmDbAA0gpDEL2";

      // Fetch the user and then set the custom claim.
      return admin.auth().getUser(userId)
          .then((userRecord) => {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());

            // Set custom user claims on this user. Set admin privilege to true.
            return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, {isAdmin: true});
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Admin claim set for user:", userId);
            res.end(JSON.stringify({
              status: "success",
              message: "User has been made an admin.",
            }));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error fetching user data or setting admin claim:",
                error);
            res.status(500).send({
              status: "error",
              message: error.message,
            });
          });
    });
```

Getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Beno\Desktop\GIT\Well Track\WellTrack Cloud Functions July 7\functions> firebase deploy --only functions --debug

[2023-07-07T13:54:55.738Z] Got source token undefined for region australia-southeast1
Build failed: ...rom lock file
npm ERR! Missing: mimic-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: error-ex@1.3.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: lines-and-columns@1.2.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: find-up@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-core-module@2.12.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: resolve-from@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@2.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: argparse@1.0.10 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global]
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-07-07T13_54_28_659Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
[2023-07-07T13:54:55.758Z] Total Function Deployment time: 50416
[2023-07-07T13:54:55.758Z] 1 Functions Deployed
[2023-07-07T13:54:55.758Z] 1 Functions Errored
[2023-07-07T13:54:55.758Z] 0 Function Deployments Aborted
[2023-07-07T13:54:55.759Z] Average Function Deployment time: 50414

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        assignAdminRole(australia-southeast1)
[2023-07-07T13:54:56.387Z] Not printing URL for HTTPS function. Typically this means it didn't match a filter or we failed deployment
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
[2023-07-07T13:54:56.391Z] >>> [apiv2][query] DELETE https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/assign_admin_role [none]
[2023-07-07T13:54:56.393Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/welltrack-b57f6/gcf/australia-southeast1/tags/list [none]
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.150Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/welltrack-b57f6/gcf/australia-southeast1/tags/list 200
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.150Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2/welltrack-b57f6/gcf/australia-southeast1/tags/list {"child":[],"manifest":{},"name":"welltrack-b57f6/gcf/australia-southeast1","tags":[]}
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.151Z] Could not find image for function projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/functions/assignAdminRole        
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.572Z] <<< [apiv2][status] DELETE https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/assign_admin_role 404
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.573Z] <<< [apiv2][body] DELETE https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/assign_admin_role {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Package \"projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/assign_admin_role\" was not found.","status":"NOT_FOUND"}}
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.577Z] Functions deploy failed.
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.578Z] {
  "endpoint": {
    "id": "assignAdminRole",
    "project": "welltrack-b57f6",
    "region": "australia-southeast1",
    "entryPoint": "assignAdminRole",
    "platform": "gcfv1",
    "runtime": "nodejs18",
    "httpsTrigger": {},
    "serviceAccount": null,
    "ingressSettings": null,
    "availableMemoryMb": null,
    "timeoutSeconds": null,
    "maxInstances": null,
    "minInstances": null,
    "vpc": null,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "FIREBASE_CONFIG": "{\"projectId\":\"welltrack-b57f6\",\"storageBucket\":\"welltrack-b57f6.appspot.com\",\"locationId\":\"australia-southeast1\"}",
      "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "welltrack-b57f6",
      "EVENTARC_CLOUD_EVENT_SOURCE": "projects/welltrack-b57f6/locations/australia-southeast1/functions/assignAdminRole"
    },
    "codebase": "default",
    "targetedByOnly": false,
    "hash": "6d6f3d9bdf037d6c769383afc2132d20e85bb5ab",
    "labels": {
      "deployment-tool": "cli-firebase"
    }
  },
  "op": "create",
  "original": {
    "name": "FirebaseError",
    "children": [],
    "exit": 1,
    "message": "Build failed: ...rom lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: mimic-fn@2.1.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: error-ex@1.3.2 from lock file\nnpm 
ERR! Missing: json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: lines-and-columns@1.2.4 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: find-up@4.1.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: is-core-module@2.12.1 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: resolve-from@5.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@2.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: argparse@1.0.10 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file\nnpm ERR! \nnpm 
ERR! Clean install a project\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Usage:\nnpm ERR! npm ci\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Options:\nnpm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]\nnpm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global]\nnpm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]\nnpm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]\nnpm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]\nnpm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]\nnpm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]\nnpm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Run \"npm help ci\" for more info\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run 
can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-07-07T13_54_28_659Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772",
    "status": 3,
    "code": 3
  }
}
[2023-07-07T13:54:57.874Z] Error: Failed to create function assignAdminRole in region australia-southeast1
    at C:\Users\Beno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:51:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.createV1Function (C:\Users\Beno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:180:32)
    at async Fabricator.createEndpoint (C:\Users\Beno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:132:13)
    at async handle (C:\Users\Beno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:88:17)

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json files and npm install, no luck and getting the same error.